# what is meant by "the integral is interpreted in the weak sense"?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, terminology, lebesgue-integral

What is meant by

> the integral is interpreted in the weak sense

in following corollary:
[image]

on page 261 of the book "An introduction to frame and Riesz bases", second edition,  by Ole Christenson.

There is no an explanation in the book.

Answer (score 3):

An integral is a limit. A limit depends on the topology you use. In a Hilbert space as $L^2(\mathbb R)$, the two most natural topologies are the *strong* one, where $f_j\to f$ means $\langle f_j-f,f_j-f\rangle\to0$ (that is, the one given by the norm), and the *weak* one, where $f_j\to f$ means $$
\langle f_j-f,g\rangle\to0\ \ \ \ \text{ for all } g\in L^2(\mathbb R). 
$$

Comment: The integrals in L2(R) seem to be lebesgue. I don't know if there is a weak and strong lebesgue integral.